# Cannot access url argument with React using async function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

With React, I want to access to a URL parameter inside an Async function.

I have been using React route as following :

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/signin/:projectUUID" element={<SignIn />} />
```

I have been trying to access the projectUUID parameter from an asycn function as follows:

```
export const EmailSendEmailMagicLink = async (callback) =>
{
  let resultState = { state: '', data: {} };

  const { projectUUID } = this.props; // ( 45th line is here )
  let project_uuid = projectUUID ? projectUUID : "";
```

(Update the question as requested below)
This is where I invoke the function :

```
const EmailSignInBtn = async (form_data, file) =>
  {
    let result = await EmailSendEmailMagicLink();
```

And this is HTML :

```
  <Box className='signup-Btn' onClick={EmailSignInBtn}>
    Get Magic Link
  </Box>
```

However, when I execute the request, I get the following error :

```
    ApiProvider.js:45 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
        at EmailSendEmailMagicLink (ApiProvider.js:45:1)
        at EmailSignInBtn (signIn.js:42:1)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
        at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
        at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
        at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
        at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
        at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)

What shall I do to access the url argument from / within the async function ?
```

Note :

When I use useParams as following

```
  const { projectUUID } = useParams();
  let project_uuid = projectUUID ? projectUUID : "";
```

I get the following error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
```

Comment: Could you show where you invoke this function?

Comment: As far as i can tell "this" does not refer to the component when it's called. If you have access to `props` in `EmailSignInBtn` function, maybe you should try this 
`await EmailSendEmailMagicLink.call(this)`.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]. The `SignIn` is what needs to access the route params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the last version of react-router-dom and you are using the `element` props in your `Route`, you can use `useParams()` from [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params).

Comment: When I use const { projectUUID } = useParams(); in EmailSendEmailMagicLink function, I get following error :

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

Comment: If you have a class component, turn it into a functional component